# Looking for a old novel about a telepath committing murders

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy

I am looking for a novel that I read in the late 80's, involving a telepath committing murders.

The book itself was fairly old even then, so was probably written in the 60s, 50s or earlier.

Here is a general breakdown of the plot as I remember it:

The story was set in the U.S. contemporary to when it was written, so early to mid 20th century. There were no sci-fi elements like space-travel, aliens or anything like that.

The main character is gathered into a group by character A and his best friend in order to do a study/investigation into the possible existence of psychic powers. After some exposition they hold a test, similar to a seance, where said supposed psychic powers are expected to make a top spin or pages turn or something similar (I don't remember exactly).

Then character A is murdered, though at first it's believed to be suicide. A repeat of the test reveals that something psychic is happening.

Eventually the main character figures out that character A was murdered by his best friend, who is the telepath. The friend had been "puppeting" character A since they were children to be better - winning at basketball, jumping off a short cliff into a lake, feeling brave in the face of danger, etc...

But character A discovered this when he once tried to do something alone (which he and his friend had done many times) only to fail - revealing that his friend had been psychically boosting him. This is what led to him starting the investigation and eventually causing the friend to dispose of him. I think the "friend" thought of character A as more of a pet than anything.

I'm not entirely sure, but I have a recollection of the main character fighting another puppetted person, jumping on the rails of a roller-coaster, while the murderer sits on a bench below and watches.

Eventually the murderer dies and the main character awakens his own psychic powers.

I think he may also have "assumed control" of the love interest, who the murderer had also been puppeting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Good description here. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to SF&F!  This is a very good first question!  I just noticed what might be a typo that could be confusing....I'm guessing that the sentence, "There was sci-fi elements like space-travel, aliens or anything like that." was meant to say, "There were no sci-fi elements like space-travel, aliens or anything like that."  If my guess is correct, you may want to edit it; it is perhaps a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm throwing this out as a WAG, even though I've never read the book in question, because the plot synopsis is so reminiscent of the 1968 movie "The Power" which was based on a novel of the same name by Frank Robinson.  The publication timeframe works out.

[https://www.amazon.com/Power-Frank-M-Robinson/dp/0312866542](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0312866542)

Comment: Yes, I have the book and it matches the description. I can edit the blurb from the back of the book unto your answer if you want.

Comment: That's it, yes. Thank you very much.